# Ignore time portion when using DateTime::createFromFormat

Tags: php, datetime

I have dates coming from database in two formats:

```
$tests[] = "2018-01-01";
$tests[] = "2018-01-01 12:34:56.789";
```

Is is possible to convert the strings to DateTime using `DateTime::createFromFormat` and ignore the time portion? I would like to use minimal code to handle both cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following format:

```
"!Y-m-d+"
```

Like so:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat("!Y-m-d+", "2018-01-01")             ->format(DateTime::ATOM); // 2018-01-01T00:00:00+05:00
echo DateTime::createFromFormat("!Y-m-d+", "2018-01-01 12:34:56.789")->format(DateTime::ATOM); // 2018-01-01T00:00:00+05:00
```

- `!` character resets all date and time components to the left of it to 1970-01-01 00:00:00. Without it, the components not specified in the format are set to components from current time.
- `+` character instructs the parser to ignore trailing characters in the date string.